# Liquibase preCondition check if enum field not exists

Tags: liquibase

how can I write a preCondition that checks if an enum value for a column does not exist?

Lets say I have table MyTable and it has a column color of type Enum with values red and green and now I want with a changeset to add a new value 'blue'.

```
<changeSet>
   <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
       <not>
          // here the check for blue not exists
       </not>
    </preConditions>

    <sql>
        alter table MyTable modify color enum (red, green, blue)
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```